# how to copy only data from one database table to another database existing table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to copy only data from one database table to another database existing table in sql server query?

Copy one database existing table to another database existing table.
anyone know,  Please tell me Sql query
[Open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enf2C.png)

Comment: Do you try anything?  Could you  share your code to us we will try to figure out your problem

Comment: `INSERT INTO <target table> (columns) SELECT columns FROM <source table>`

Comment: Does both databases exist on the same server?

Comment: Yes, both databases are existed on the same server

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is getting down-voted because it doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you and doesn't show any effort on your part to solve the problem. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. [SO - How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, regarding posting pictures, [Why not upload images of code...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584)

Comment: A Merge statement (or it's equivalent) is probably the best answer but it requires two tables with primary keys. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017].  That works whether the table is empty or filled.  Also, while you can post images on Stack Overflow, it's discouraged.  Especially this question, since it's so relatively simple that it shouldn't even need a picture.  **Take the extra 10-15 minutes to post the full create-table DDL and what you tried.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
INSERT INTO DataBase2.dbo.table2
SELECT * FROM DataBase1.dbo.table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into <target table name>(columns)
select columns 
from <source table name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking:

```
 INSERT INTO [databaseName].[schemaName].[table2]
 SELECT * FROM [databaseName].[schemaName].[table1]
```

If you are more specific in your question, I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: tables are in different databases

Comment: @Anjig the query will still work you just have to specify this.

Answer (score 0):

Generate scripts in SQL Server Management Studio from one database's table and run the generated script in another database. [image: See the picture]

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you want to copy data from all columns keeping the same order in two tables.
 If both tables exist in your database use

```
insert into targetTable 
select * from sourceTable
```

If not, use

```
select * into targetTable 
from sourceTable
```

In the second case, the targetTable will inherit the datatypes from the sourceTable (not the keys, indexes, etc..)

Comment: Your first assertion is incorrect on every count. `INSERT INTO` does not require using all columns, does not require that they be in the same order, and does not require that they be in the same database. Except in very narrow circumstances, `SELECT...INTO` is a poor choice. https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/use-selectinto-statement There just isn't much that's helpful in your answer that wasn't in all of the answers posted previously.

Comment: The original post mentioned copying data from table to another. Thus I did not use (columns) after targetTable  and * afterwards. If copying with select was the preffered option (case 1 above) and  then the same order should exist. Otherwise all columns should appear in parentheses and in select statement respectively. As for your reference link it is helpful but I already mentioned that  index, constraints are not included. For development purposes it is still a fine choice and faster to implement.

PS: The original post was modified (existing tables) so you are right, my answer won't help